# SAML2 Connection For Grails application

Tags: grails, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I am  totally new in SAML SSO connection so, can anyone provide me the sample codes and libraries(jar etc) to establish the connection, The following parameters are provided by the third party application to which i need to connect via SAML2,

1. SAML Assertion Consumer Hub
2. Audience Entity ID
3. IssuerID
4. URL (for POSTing)
5. UserID/Username
6. A level 2 (also called Class 2) certificate

Comment: Since you are not mentioning the Grails version, i assume 3.  So you can just use any spring-booty stuff.  E.g. https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/spring-boot-security-saml

Comment: I am using grails -2.5.1 and i just want to request to the provided url in order to get the token and browse the their application using that token. Is there any other examples to accomplished this?